# databricks-connect: invalid shard address

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-connect

I am trying to run some code using databricks-connect, but I am suddenly running into this error,

```
22/06/24 13:24:48 ERROR SparkClientManager: Fail to get the SparkClient
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.databricks.service.SparkServiceConnectionException: Invalid shard address
```

Everything was working fine until today. It looks like some of my colleagues are getting the same error as well, out of nowhere.

I came across this post as well, but it only provides the link to an article that explains how to set up db-connect on VS Code,

https://community.databricks.com/s/question/0D53f00001fckBSCAY/databricksconnect-invalid-shard-address

How can this be resolved?

Comment: The answer given by @Alex Ott solved this issue, however, I also found this article in the Microsoft documentation that may be of use,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/kb/dev-tools/dbconnect-protoserializer-stackoverflow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's issue that did arise recently due the way how the host is parsed - to fix it, remove trailing slash (`/`) from the Databricks workspace host.  I.e., `https://adb-131442342.9.azuredatabricks.net/` should be `https://adb-131442342.9.azuredatabricks.net`

Answer (score 0):

> Everything was working fine until today.

If it was working fine then this should be some internal network issue which you try to resolve by re-routing the private endpoints and also you can try to restart the cluster on `databricks-cli` using below command:

`databricks clusters restart --cluster-id 0802-090441-honks846`